# How to import raw text data into Evernote?

Tags: evernote

Say, I have a todo.txt file with one line per item. Is there a way to import it into evernote so that each line shows up as a separate note? I can't find a way to do this in the Evernote UI on the PC.

Comment: If I were you, I'd head on over to stackoverflow after looking into `enscript createnote` [source](https://dev.evernote.com/documentation/local/chapters/windows.php)

Comment: I couldn't figure it out in a batch file, I tried, but you'll need something to open the text file, for each line store line to variable, call enscript createnote /p blank.txt /i variable. blank.txt will need to be a text file with a null character in it, otherwise enscript doesn't work correctly

Comment: Added the command line command to my answer, couldn't get a batch file to work, but it does what you want it to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do it from command line:

`For /F "tokens=*" %G in (path to todo.txt) do start ENscript.exe createnote /s blank.txt /i "%G"`

This requires you run command prompt at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Evernote\Evernote` that has `blank.txt` with a null character.

You can change it up by changing the paths to either text line or put the entire address of ENscript in, to run it from anywhere.

[image]

For some reason, I can't write a batch file to do this..

Comment: Thanks, sounds like what I need! How do I make a blank.txt file with Notepad? (just not sure what is a Null character)

Comment: @Joe just open notepad and press `enter` and save as `blank.txt` or whatever